# Dictionary<string, string> -> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Tags: c#, dictionary

I created and initialized quite a large Dictionary and got this error when starting the application:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in      PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Zeilennummer "3" und Zeilenposition "9" von "Durch den Aufruf des     
Konstruktors für Typ "AbiZeitung.MainWindow", der den angegebenen Bindungseinschränkungen 
entspricht,    wurde eine Ausnahme ausgelöst.".

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Here is a part of the Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> teacherList = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {"Mr", "M"},
        {"Mr", "D"},
        {"Mr", "S"},
        {"Mr", "W"}
    };
```

Any guess why this happens?

Comment: The xaml parse exception is misleading, this must be happening in the constructor of a wpf control.

Comment: @justin.m.chase The "real" exception in WPF is typically nested in the inner exceptions of the `XamlParseException` - often more than one layer down...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Dictionary<T,U>` needs to have *unique keys*.  Right now, your collection initializer will raise an exception (`ArgumentException`) when it tries to add `{"Mr","D"}`, as "Mr" is already a key.

For details, see [Dictionary.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k.aspx), under exceptions:

> ArgumentException:         An element with the same key already exists in the Dictionary.

If your View creates this dictionary, even indirectly (ie: it's in a ViewModel generated from the xaml), you'll get an exception, which in turn will cause the `XamlParseException` to occur.

If you need a collection like this, I recommend making an `ObservableCollection<T>` (or `List<T>` if this won't change) of a custom type which contains the two strings.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the exception says but you can't use same key more than one time for [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

> Represents a collection of keys and values.

In your code `"Mr"` is your key. All pairs have to had *unique keys*.

> As long as an object is used as a key in the Dictionary,
>   it must not change in any way that affects its hash value. Every key
>   in a Dictionary must be unique according to the
>   dictionary's equality comparer. A key cannot be null, but a value can
>   be, if the value type TValue is a reference type.